# how to select IPs in same network in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table include IP addresses and their netmasks, now I want select IPs from table those are in the same network by network address.

```
   ip_adress    |  netmask
----------------|-----------
 192.168.13.25  |    29    
 192.168.13.26  |    29
 192.168.13.1   |    30
 192.168.13.2   |    30
```

for example, I want IPs from table those are in the network address 192.168.13.24/29:

```
   ip_adress    |  netmask
----------------|-----------
 192.168.13.25  |    29    
 192.168.13.26  |    29
```

Comment: But! The two resulted `ip_adress` are not in the same network address of `192.168.1.24/29`

Comment: why? `192.168.13.24/29` is the network address for `192.168.13.26/29`, that's not right?

Comment: oh, I'm sorry it's `192.168.13.24/29`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PostgreSQL's [Network Address Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-net.html) you can easly get it with :

```
SELECT * FROM network_adresse_table 
WHERE network(cast(format('%1$s/%2$s',ip_adress,netmask) as inet)) = 
cast('192.168.13.24/29' as inet)
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9f8af/1)

Comment: I am not fan of flatted functions but this query is working.

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL actually has a native `inet` type, meant for storing IP addresses with their netmask in a single field, along with specialized operators for matching those.

Example:

```
test=# \d inetdemo 
  Table "public.inetdemo"
 Column | Type | Modifiers 
--------+------+-----------
 addr   | inet | 

test=# select * from inetdemo;
       addr       
------------------
 192.168.13.25/29
 192.168.13.26/29
 192.168.13.1/30
 192.168.13.2/30
(4 rows)

test=# select * from inetdemo where addr >>= '192.168.13.25/29';
       addr       
------------------
 192.168.13.25/29
 192.168.13.26/29
(2 rows)
```

For the full story, [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/datatype-net-types.html) explains the `inet` datatype (and its brother, `cidr`, which is not what you need), whereas [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/functions-net.html) explains the operators and functions you can use on `inet` and `cidr` data types. Take note of the `masklen` and `host` functions if you need to be able to get the ip address and/or netmask separately:

```
test=# select host(addr) as "ip_address", masklen(addr) as "netmask" from inetdemo;
  ip_address   | netmask 
---------------+---------
 192.168.13.25 |      29
 192.168.13.26 |      29
 192.168.13.1  |      30
 192.168.13.2  |      30
(4 rows)
```

Comment: This is way better, efficient query. Simple and explicit content.